# Wave equation near two boundaries in n dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

Consider a function $u(t, x, y)$ defined on $t \in (t_i, t_f) \ , x > 0 \ , y \in \mathbb{R}^{n - 2}$ satisfying the wave equation (here $\Delta_y$ is the Laplace operator w.r.t. the variable $y$)
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
-u_{tt}(t, x, y) + \partial_x^2u(t, x, y) + \Delta_y u(t, x, y) &= 0 \ ,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

in the presence of two boundaries equipped with the boundary conditions
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
u(t_i, x, y) &= u_i(x, y) \ , \\
u(t_f, x, y) &= u_f(x, y) \ , \\
u(t, x, 0) &= f(t, x) \ , \\
\partial_x u(t, x, 0) &= g(t, x) \ .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I wish to solve this PDE in terms of the functions $u_i \ , u_f \ , f$ and $g$.

Can anyone help me solve this? I'm confused due to the presence of two boundaries instead of one.